# Ubuntu MATE thinks it knows my IP address but is wrong

Tags: wifi, ubuntu, image

I am trying to boot my Raspberry Pi from an image (I created) burned to an SD card. I set up the image on another Raspberry Pi (we will call it 4GB). `etc/NetworkManager` has the password of the WIFI stored. When the new (we will call it 8GB) Raspberry Pi boots from the image it (8GB) logs onto the wireless with the correct password. The issue though is that 8GB Ubuntu thinks it knows the IP address but it is using the other Raspberry Pi (4GB)'s IP address bound on my router to the 4GB MAC address.

How do I get 8GB to accept the IP address assigned to it by my router?

It is important to mention that this Raspberry Pi is headless, so this configurations is quite troublesome.

Also of note `etc/NetworkManager`'s configuration file for the WIFI network is set to Auto DHCP mode.

The NetworkManager profile for this wireless device says:

```
[connection]
id=THESSID
uuid=aa5deb3d-9378-4713-b60f-6955a3c368c2
type=wifi
interface-name=wlan0
permissions=

[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=THECORRECTSSID

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=THEPASSWORD

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

[proxy]
```

How does one configure NetworkManager for a connection by altering it's configuration files?

How would 8GB inherently know what 4GB's IP address was?

Comment: Without detail of what you have done no one can answer. Each Pi has **unique MAC**. NOTE that `NetworkManager` **requires** each interface to be configured individually - it is NOT designed for computers like the Pi which allows the whole OS to be transferred to another machine.

Comment: @Milliways how does one configure `NetworkManager` for a connection by altering it's configuration files? How would 8GB inherently **know** what 4GB's IP address was? 
As far as _doing_ something to the OS, nothing has been _done_ as it relates to `NetworkManager.` All that I have done is install a program which runs on Java script.

Comment: DO NOT ask additional questions in Comments, edit your Question. `NetworkManager` is NOT designed to be manually configured; while this is possible it is complex. It is designed to be run from the GUI or `nmcli`. Transferring a SD Card to another machine is hardly doing nothing. Normally `NetworkManager` uses Predictable Network Interface Names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forced my router to lock the IP address of 8GB to a .181.
My router said that 8GB had an IP address of .181 but 8GB was also responding to .174.
Then I restarted.
It turns out the 8GB was *asking* for the IP of 4GB and it was being given because 4GB wasn't currently on the network.

Answer (score 1):

"How would 8GB inherently know what 4GB's IP address was?"

Most DHCP clients cache leases and only request a new lease when the lease time expires.
If you have cloned a SD Card you will have cloned all the cached data.
If you had used the normal **Predictable Network Interface Names** this would not be an issue.

DHCP clients have a command to release or rebind interfaces; this differs between clients.

I do not know what `NetworkManager` uses.

The normal Debian tool uses `sudo dhclient -v interface` and stores leases in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases`